# How is this wireless mode called?

Tags: wifi, bridge

I have the following situation and I don't know how to ask google.

I have a cabled LAN segment, lets say 192.168.1.X. One of the nodes there is a wifi router 192.168.1.3 that creates wireless segment 192.168.2.X for some laptops.

I want to put all of the computers in the same network (192.168.1.X) and not to maintain 2 different networks (1.X and 2.X). I don't want to have a gateway or firewall between them. Is this possible? What is this mode called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want your router to perform all the routing, not your AP. So you just need to use it as a hub instead of a router.

Comment: I haven't seen a 'hub' mode in the routers that I have used before.

Comment: because it doesn't exist. SOHO Wireless Routers can often act as simple access point, but this mode is usually called AP Mode. On some other firmwares you just need to disable the wan port. The logical network operation you perform is indeed "bridging" the wlan branch of your network with the physical one, but in most SOHO Routers, "bridges" are advanced functions having to do with joining more access points together etc.

Answer (score 4):

You are probably looking for "bridging". Typically, an access point will do this by default. Performing routing and firewall functionality as you describe it is an advanced configuration not every access point device would support.

Comment: Is it client bridge or wireless bridge? Or different manifacturers has different names for that mode?

Comment: Neither. You want to disable your WAN port and make the router act like an Access Point. Client Bridge and Wireless Bridge both refers to advanced configurations that you don't need. You could post your router model so that we could identify the right option for your particular router/firmware combination but overall i'd say to look in the web interface of the router for "AP Mode" "WAN Port: Disabled" and so on.

Comment: +1 for ItsGC! That was it. I've connected the LAN cable for the cabled segment into one of the device LAN ports, set its IP to match one of the 1.X network (for maintenance), disabled WAN port and set wireless mode to "AP". No bridging at all, just "dumb switch" :)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to ask if the IPs in the network are assigned by a DHCP server or manually assigned?

I would assume that it is DHCP assigned, therefore I would suggest that you disable the DHCP assignment on the wireless AP. Leave the assignment to the DHCP server and you should not have the issue with 2 different network segment.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: IPs are manually assigned, but a DHCP can be used (and it will be - in the near future). The current problem is that if a laptop requests a DHCP address that request won't go further than the wifi router.